# Dependency Injection - Create object from interface

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, simple-injector

I'm doing some tests to dependency injection + mvc and I have a question.

Inside a service, how may I create an object (trough interface) which will be the result of the method?

I've discovered that an abstract factory may resolve this but some people say that it's an anti-pattern and it's a service-locator.

I've done something like this:

```
public class ObjectFactory : IFactory
{
    readonly Container container;

    public ObjectFactory(Container container)
    {
        this.container = container;

    }

    public T Create<T>()
        where T : class
    {
        return (T)this.container.GetInstance<T>();
    }
}
```

then I use it like this:

```
public class CacheService : ICacheService
{
    readonly IFactory factory;

    public CacheService(IFactory factory)
    {
        this.factory = factory;
    }

    private void Insert(string name, object value)
    {
        if (this.CacheAvailable())
        {
            Remove(name);

            // This line where I ask for the container to resolve this interface
            ICacheItemWrapper item = factory.Create<ICacheItemWrapper>();
            item.Value = value;

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(name, item, null, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        }
    }

    /* HIDDEN CODE */
}
```

Is this still an anti-pattern?

What changes should I do?

It feels wrong to do it like this...

Comment: Can the `CacheService` constructor simply require an instance of `ICacheItemWrapper` instead of `IFactory`?  That would resolve the "anti-pattern" problem by advertising on the constructor what the dependency is.  There are generally different schools of thought on the matter.  Personally I find a service locator to be tremendously useful when refactoring DI into a legacy codebase over time, but would prefer to provide specific dependencies directly when building a new codebase.

Comment: But what if I need to use the same object in different methods and each method needs a clean object of that type?

Comment: Interesting.  I wonder if a factory specific to that dependency type would itself be a meaningful dependency.  It would wrap the inner dependency, but itself be responsible for providing a "clean instance".  (Assuming the instance itself can't provide that functionality, and I can't think of a reason why it can't although that doesn't mean the edge case doesn't exist.)  One might think of it as a "service locator" for that specific dependency, as it performs a similar function.  But it is more coupled to the dependency itself and "part of" that dependency.  Just thinking out loud really.

Comment: Ultimately, what we're discussing is a contrived example of a dogmatic concept.  In the end, only you know the additional concerns and constraints in the system you're building.  And only you will be able to make an educated guess on what will be easier to support and maintain in that system going forward, attempting to predict future points of change in the system.  Regardless of any patterns or practices in theory and examples, the bottom line is ease of supportability of the system.

Comment: I see. What you are saying is that if an object must be reused in different methods then it should be wrapped in a factory which is responsible for cleaning the object, or even the object cleaning himself.

Comment: "Must" and "should" are strong words at this point.  I would certainly hope that the object itself is meaningfully re-usable.  That would be my first goal.  If it truly can't be, then I'd wrap it in an object whose responsibility is to provide meaningful instances of that non-re-usable object.  This responsibility seems *similar to* a service locator.

Comment: Yes I agree, sometimes we don't need to follow 100% the meta. I did it this way because it's a simple way to get viewmodels inside services. Those viewmodels do not contain any logic, they are just data containers. I'll think about this for a while before any conclusion.

Comment: But by doing that, I would need to create SEVERAL different "factories" to create each "viewmodel"

Comment: If a dependency is itself a view model with no meaningful logic, and it's truly a non-domain DTO meant only for application-layer consumption, then I'd also question whether it needs to be injected in the first place.  A DTO sounds like something that can safely be instantiated wherever it's needed.

Comment: Ok, that seems... logical. Someone once said me that data containers don't need abstraction.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129273/discussion-between-leandro-soares-and-david).

Comment: @David is right. DI is meant for injecting components containing the application's behavior. Runtime data should not be injected into constructors but should be passed along method calls on an constructed object graph of components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is much simpler than you would expect.

Since the factory you are injecting contains a `Create<T>()` method that is unconstraint in the number of types that can be requested, this is an implementation of the Service Locator anti-pattern.

Furthermore, the only service that your `CacheService` component really needs is the `ICacheItemWrapper`. The `IFactory` only adds an extra layer of indirection that increases complexity and complicates testing.

Instead you should inject `ICacheItemWrapper` directly into the constructor of `CacheService`:

```
public CacheService(ICacheItemWrapper wrapper) { ... }
```

You might think this answer is too simplistic, since this would obvously lead to problems in case your `CacheService` should outlive the `ICacheItemWrapper`. For instance, in case the `CacheService` is registered as `Singleton`, while the `ICacheItemWrapper` is `Scoped`, injecting the `ICacheItemWrapper` into the `CacheService` will lead to a [Captive Dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/02/captive-dependency/).

When this happens, you might be tempted to change the `ICacheItemWrapper` dependency to a `Func<ICacheItemWrapper>` but doing so can cause sweeping changes throughout your application. Furthermore, a `Func<T>` dependency is a leaky abstraction, since now the consumer of that dependency now has knowledge about the 'volatiliness' of that dependency. This should be of no concern to its consumers. Injecting a `Func<T>` also complicates the consumers and their tests that now have to deal with a delegate returning the abstraction instead of simply having to deal with the abstraction.

In the case of a Captive Dependency, the solution is to wrap the short-lived component into a proxy class that creates the component on depend. This way consumers are unaffected to this change. Example:

```
public class CacheItemWrapperProxy : ICacheItemWrapper
{
    private readonly Func<ICacheItemWrapper> wrapperProvider;
    public CacheItemWrapperProxy(Func<ICacheItemWrapper> wrapperProvider) {
        this.wrapperProvider = wrapperProvider;
    }

    // ICacheItemWrapper method(s)
    public object GetItem(string key) => this.wrapperProvider().GetItem(key);
}
```

The `CacheItemWrapperProxy` implements `ICacheItemWrapper` and this allows it to be injected into its consumers, without the consumers having to change. Do note that the `CacheItemWrapperProxy` itself does depend on `Func<T>`, but the use of this `Func<T>` isolated and the `CacheItemWrapperProxy` can be located inside the application's [Composition Root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot/). Again, the rest of the application will be unaffected.

This is how you register this in Simple Injector:

```
container.Register<ICacheItemWrapper, CacheItemWrapperImpl>(Lifestyle.Scoped);
container.RegisterDecorator<ICacheItemWrapper, CacheItemWrapperProxy>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
container.Register<ICacheService, CacheService>(Lifestyle.Singleton);
```

Do note that Simple Injector has no out-of-the-box support for injecting `Func<T>` dependencies. This is deliberate, since -as explained above- your application components should not depend on `Func<T>`. The exception to the rule is Simple Injector's decorator registration facility. The `RegisterDecorator` method does have native support for handling `Func<T>` dependencies, in the sole case that this `T` is the decorated type (in your case `ICacheItemWrapper`).

Long story short, always use constructor injection, and prevent injecting `Func<T>` dependencies into your application components.

Comment: I see, but isn't this a bit overwhelming since I've several viewmodels which I need to have the same behavior. I'm afraid that this will grow too quickly. Or, am I wrong?

Comment: @LeandroSoares Update your question and show some code. It's impossible to say anything useful without some concrete examples

Comment: I'll once I can (still today). Thank you @Steven.

Comment: Using `Func<>` to replace `new` or `container.GetInstance<>` is that bad? I mean, at least it's not part of service-locator pattern, it's still verified in the container and I don't need to create a "Proxy" for each class I need to create like this.

Answer (score 1):

Yes; you're wrapping the Service Locator anti-pattern, but it's still an antipattern.

Instead, you should make your constructor accept a `Func<ICacheItemWrapper>` (most IoC containers support this).

This way, your ctor still lists its exact requirements, and it's still easy to create an instance of your class directly without IoC.

Comment: I've seen this, but if I use 100 viewmodels in my service, I need to create 100 delegates to that purpose :/ isn't it wrong like this?

Comment: I just want something plain simple which may create different objects. Those objects that will be created are only data containers and will not contain any logic. Is it still wrong?

Comment: @LeandroSoares why do you need 100 delegates?

Comment: I was giving an example. If I need `N` different instantiations inside my service I would need `N` delegates.
I'm not following the handler pattern, just the service pattern which will handle several different objects.